# Viewing all library permissions, site wide

Tags: 2010, permissions, library, libraries

Our site has a list of about 10 departments. Each one has some sub sites which contain librarys. Once a week I have to check all these libraries and check the permissions to make sure only the people who should have access, do.

I currently do this by navigating to each team site, find the library on the left, open it, go to permission view, check the permissions, go back, go to the next library, repeat. This is a very tedious and time consuming way of doing it.

Is there a way of viewing every single libraries permissions on the site collection in one go? I could maybe import that into excel and filter out the junk I don't need.

Or am I truly stuck using this, click, click, click tedium?

Edit: We are NOT running Sharepoint 2013 and have no access to powershell. AFAIK.

Comment: If you have access to the SharePoint server and your user is a Farm Admin, then you can do this through PowerShell scripts.

Comment: @Daniel-Ziga, Sorry, but I don't know how to do that. Our systems are on XP and are locked down. I can't find a powershell in any the start menu (unless it is done elsewhere). Again, sorry to be dumb here, I am learning sharepoint on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is by using PowerShell Script. Check this one : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permission-2840f327

It's a script that checks for a specific user access, but you can easily adapt it to target your libraries only and get permissions for all users.

Comment: We are not using Sharepoint 2013 and AFAIK, I have no access to powershell on our locked down, XP machines.